# Unable to complete SSL/TLS handshake and set local cert chain file

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, tcp, reactphp

I can create a ssl key and certificate with the following script:

```
<?php
$name='example_ss';  //Will add _key.pem, _crt.pem, _csr.pem
$data = [
    "countryName" => "US",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "CA",
    "localityName" => "San Francisco",
    "organizationName" => "example.net",
    "organizationalUnitName" => "example.net",
    "commonName" => "example.net",
    "emailAddress" => "exampleATgmailDOTcom"
];
$pem_passphrase = 'secret';

// Generate certificate
$key = openssl_pkey_new();
$csr = openssl_csr_new($data, $key);
$csr = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $key, 365);

// Generate PEM file
$pem = [];
openssl_x509_export($csr, $pem[0]);
file_put_contents($name.'_crt.pem', $pem[0]);
//openssl_pkey_export($key, $pem[1], $pem_passphrase); //Remove $pem_passphrase for none
openssl_pkey_export($key, $pem[1]); //Remove $pem_passphrase for none
$pem = implode($pem);

file_put_contents($name.'_key.pem', $pem);
```

Move them as required:

```
sudo mv example_ss_crt.pem /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_ss_crt.pem
sudo mv example_ss_key.pem /etc/pki/tls/private/example_ss_key.pem
```

And everything works find.

But when I create them manually: (w/ and w/o using -sha256)

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout example_ss_key.pem -out example_ss_crt.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

And move them as I did for the previous, I get the following error:

```
Unable to complete SSL/TLS handshake: stream_socket_enable_crypto():
Unable to set local cert chain file `/etc/pki/tls/private/example_ss_key.pem';
Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer
```

What is the difference between these two sets of keys and how do I create them manually?  I don't think it is relevant, but they are being used for a tcp sockets connection between Centos7 and a Raspberry Pi.

EDIT.  The server is created with the following script.  I am not using a passphrase.

```
    $loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $server = new \React\Socket\TcpServer($this->host['url'].':'.$this->host['port'], $loop);
    if($this->host['tls']) {
        $server = $this->host['privateKey']
        ?new \React\Socket\SecureServer($server, $loop, ['local_cert' => $this->host['privateKey'],'passphrase' => $this->host['passphrase'] ])
        :new \React\Socket\SecureServer($server, $loop, ['local_cert' => $this->host['privateKey'] ]);
    }
```

Dummy mistake.  http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

> local_cert string Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It
>   must be a PEM encoded file which contains your certificate and private
>   key. It can optionally contain the certificate chain of issuers. The
>   private key also may be contained in a separate file specified by
>   local_pk

.

Comment: You don't say where the error message is coming from and you only show the code to generate the certificate and not where you use it. The error message *Unable to set local cert chain file ... example_ss_key.pem* suggests that you've used they key file `example_ss_key.pem` as certificate and not as key.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Error occurs when client attempts to connect.  I am pretty sure I am using the right ones, but could be wrong.   The funny part is how the first key works when I use the php script to create it.  I am now thinking maybe I need to combine them?

Comment: Combining key and cert into a single file should at least make it impossible to inadvertently switch the file names for key and cert, which I suspect is the case in your (still unknown) code.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I will check in detail.  Given your confidence, I suspect you are correct as well.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Yes, you are correct.  Thank you

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I don't know what is going on!!!  I switched them, and it still doesn't work.  Then I combined them, and it works.  Why?  Thanks

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  Turns out I didn't read the man.  See end of my original post.